# RACADM reboot to Lifecycle Controller

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, drac

I am using RACADM to manage my Dell servers. I am familiar with the OneTimeBootSeq, but I do not see a way to force the server into the F10 Lifecycle Controller via this method. Is it possible to push a server to the lifecycle controller via RACADM?

Answer (score 1):

Give something like these a try.

```
# racadm set iDRAC.ServerBoot.BootOnce Enabled
# racadm set iDRAC.ServerBoot.FirstBootDevice F10
```

Dell support informed me it was not possible. But it is an option through the iDRAC web GUI, so I went and set it there, then checked all the iDRAC settings. I got the above commands by walking through all the racadm iDRAC settings.

To get back to normal:

```
# racadm set iDRAC.ServerBoot.FirstBootDevice Normal
# racadm set iDRAC.ServerBoot.BootOnce Disabled
```